# Add form elements after Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm building a form that allows users to enter a word, and when they tab off I query a dictionary(Wordnik.com) to retrieve the definitions, and add the definitions as radio button selections to the form. The javascript picks up the word, calls the get_definition function in my WordsController and queries the dictionary API, but I can't seem to get the partial to render (right now it just prints out "<%= escape_javascript.....%>")

PS: I also tried querying the api directly with jquery (so I'm not hitting the get_definitions function) but I couldn't get the request to send, so I'm sticking with the above method for now.

words_controller:

```
def index
    @words = Word.where(user_id: current_user)
    @word = current_user.words.new
    @defs = Array.new
end

def get_definition
    @defs = Wordnik.word.get_definitions(params['word'])
    render nothing: true
end
```

javascript:

```
$('input#word_name').blur(function(){
    var word = $('input#word_name').val();
    $.ajax({
            url: '/words/get_definition',
            data: 'word='+word
    })
    $('#addDefinitionContainer').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'words/definitions', locals: {f: f}) %>")
})
```

_definitions partial:

```
<% @defs.each do |definition| %>
   <div class="definition_choice">
   <%= f.label definition %>
   <%= f.radio_button :definition, "yes" %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You need to add a success callback to your `$.ajax()` call, not try to use server-side code in the line after it. Or use `$.ajax({...}).done(data){ $('#addDefinitionContainer').html(data); });`

Comment: Where is your javascript located? Is it inlined right in the view? Or in a separate js file within the public directory?

Comment: @nnnnnn I tried both adding "success: function(data){ $("#addDefinitionContainer").html(data); }" inside the ajax call as well as "$.ajax({...}).done(data){ $('#addDefinitionContainer').html(data); }". The latter method doesn't even call the get_definitions function when I tried it.

Comment: @JonahKatz Right now I just have it in the application.js file

Comment: If your version of jQuery predates the introduction of `.done()` then `.done()` would stop it working. But `success : function(data){...` should work. What actually happened when you tried it?

Comment: @nnnnnn nothing was injected into the page (nothing visual happened) but I could see that it at least queried the function.

Comment: I'd put a `console.log(data)` or even `alert(data)` into the success function to check if the function is called. If it isn't, I'd add an error handler and see if jQuery reports an error.

Comment: @nnnnnn I was able to get the function call to work, and decided to try to generate the radio buttons for each definition through jquery. However, even though I can get them added to the page, when I submit the form, the chosen value doesn't get sent with it. This probably due to them not originally being on the page. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to render the ruby partial in javascript I decided to manually add the form elements instead, in js. After the ajax call to my ruby method, I call the following method as the callback:

```
function addDefsToForm(data){           
    $.each(data, function(index,item){
        var radio = $('<input />', { id: 'word_definition_'+index, name: 'word_definition', type: 'radio', value: item['text']});
        $('#addDefinitionContainer').append(radio);
        $('#addDefinitionContainer').append(item['text']+"<br />");
    });

};
```

This adds a radio button (with associated text) to the page for each definition I receive. However, the radio button chosen by the user doesn't get send along with the word in the POST request. The solution of which is to call the jquery serialize() function on the form upon submission:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    $(this).serialize();
});
```

I suppose since these added form elements (radio buttons) aren't in the DOM when the page first renders, they won't be looked for upon form submission. The serialize function goes over the form as it is now and prepares a new string to be sent.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you cant have ruby code within a .js file. Even if you inline the js code, youll still have issues.

Thankfully, Rails has build in libraries to help you use ajax. Take a look at this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ajax_on_rails.html